# I can't get typography from my custom theme Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to use mixin to reuse my custom theme on my custom component bu i meet some troubles
I set my typography and theme like this :

```
...
$headline-6: mat.define-typography-level(
 $font-family: Marianne Regular,
  $font-weight: 400,
  $font-size: --fontSizeMedium,
);
... 
$light-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $headline-1: $headline-1,
  $headline-2: $headline-2,
  $headline-3: $headline-3,
  $headline-4: $headline-4,
  $headline-5: $headline-5,
  $headline-6: $headline-6,
  $subtitle-1: $subtitle-1,
  $subtitle-2: $subtitle-2,
  $body-1: $body-1,
  $body-2: $body-2,
  $caption: $caption,
  $button: $button,
);
$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $light-primary,
    accent: $light-accent,
    warm: $lighy-warm,
  ),
  typography: $light-typography,
  density: -3
));
```

my custom component mixin look like this

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@mixin color($theme) {
  // Get the color config from the theme.
  $color-config: mat.get-color-config($theme);

  // Get the primary color palette from the color-config.
  $primary-palette: map.get($color-config, 'primary');

  app-railway {
    // Read the 500 hue from the primary color palette.
    color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, 500);
  }
}

@mixin typography($theme) {
  // Get the typography config from the theme.
  $typography-config: mat.get-typography-config($theme);

  .railway_container {

    h2, h3{
      font-family: mat.font-family($typography-config);
    }

  }
}

@mixin theme($theme) {
  $color-config: mat.get-color-config($theme);
  @if $color-config != null {
    @include color($theme);
  }

  $typography-config: mat.get-typography-config($theme);
  @if $typography-config != null {
    @include typography($theme);
  }
}
```

and i call it like this

```
@include railway.theme($light-theme);
```

the color works well and my typography works well in angular material component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i needed add the font-family in the map where i defined my typography, by default it takes Roboto

```
$light-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: Marianne,
  $headline-1: $headline-1,
  $headline-2: $headline-2,
  $headline-3: $headline-3,
  $headline-4: $headline-4,
  $headline-5: $headline-5,
  $headline-6: $headline-6,
  $subtitle-1: $subtitle-1,
  $subtitle-2: $subtitle-2,
  $body-1: $body-1,
  $body-2: $body-2,
  $caption: $caption,
  $button: $button,
  $overline: $overline,
);
```

Unfortunately the angular material doc doesn't say anithing about this

Answer (score 0):

you should add **mat.typography-hierarchy($light-typography)** to apply the typography
this code runs with **"@angular/material": "^16.1.3"**,

```css
$light-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: Marianne,
  $headline-1: $headline-1,
  $headline-2: $headline-2,
  $headline-3: $headline-3,
  $headline-4: $headline-4,
  $headline-5: $headline-5,
  $headline-6: $headline-6,
  $subtitle-1: $subtitle-1,
  $subtitle-2: $subtitle-2,
  $body-1: $body-1,
  $body-2: $body-2,
  $caption: $caption,
  $button: $button,
  $overline: $overline,
);

@include mat.typography-hierarchy($light-typography);
```